# Detect Paper and text without Vision Framework on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, image-recognition

I'm developing an app which will open a camera and take a picture If camera detects a paper. I was searching this for a while but I'm not sure which will be best approach in 2018 :)

First P.S: I need to support from iOS 9.0 so I can't use Vision Framework which is working only after iOS 11.0.
What I found;

**Tesseract OCR:**
As I searched, this is most common used library after Vision Framework. As I see, there are two common problems with this library. One is It can't detect If it is a paper and other one is It may have problems with small amount of texts. (Papers which will be scanned has only one line of number like in credit cards)

[OCR match frame´s position to field in credit card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046590/ocr-match-frame%C2%B4s-position-to-field-in-credit-card)

> Your first problem is that most OCRs are not optimised for small amounts of text that take up most of the "page"

https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS

**OpenCV:** This is the second library I found for text recognition but As I see this is a old way of doing it. Therefore, I'm not sure If it is fast and reliable.

https://medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1

Example App which does paper recognation great:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/evernote-scannable/id883338188?mt=8

Comment: *I need to support from iOS 9.0* — why? As of Apple's [latest published statistics](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/), which as of this writing are three months outdated, iOS 9 represents less than 8% of devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://github.com/robertoferraz/OCRSlicer) library called OCRSlicer (I wrote :D) for the small amounts of text as you mentioned.

Regarding the paper detection, you would need something else.. Open CV could do that with contrast difference :)

Another suggestion is using [Firebase for OCR](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-text)

Answer (score 1):

For paper detection you can use  CIDetector of Core Image

**iOS 8.0+**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cirectanglefeature

> A detected rectangle feature is not necessarily rectangular in the plane of the image; rather, the feature identifies a shape that may be rectangular in space but which appears in perspective in the image—for example, a paper or book on a desk. The properties of a CIRectangleFeature object identify its corners in image coordinates.
>
> For example, you can use rectangle feature detection together with the CIPerspectiveCorrection filter to detect rectangular objects in an image or video and transform them to their original orientation.

Comment: I searched this one but It works quite mistaken. It can detect rectangles but not just papers, for example part of a desk. Correct me If I'm mistaken but As I searched, when detecting paper, I need to get some color type of images?

Comment: Vision Framework is the evolution of the cidetector, with cidetector you can also detect text, barcodes and faces, this is the only thing that is natively in ios, if it doesn't fit what you need you will have to use other external libraries like opencv.   ---------  I don't understand your question. I need to get some color type of images?

Comment: I want to detect a paper and text on iOS 9.0 >= devices.

Comment: I meant that I don't understand  ----  **I need to get some color type of images?**